# Selecting a range with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy column k(rows 4 to the end) & column c(rows 4 to the end), Copy them, and Paste them into into column BL(starting at row 4) & column BM(Starting at row 4) without duplicates. (basically trying to replicate the first provided code but to start at row 4 instead of row 1.

Here is the following code I have working which will do full rows:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K:K", "C:C").Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BL1")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BL:BL", "BM:BM").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
```

Here is the attempted code which seems to take from K to C, instead of K and C.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:K" & Lastrow, "C4:C" & Lastrow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BL3")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BL4:BL" & Lastrow, "BM4:BM" & Lastrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do two separate copy pastes and look to how I changed the range on the RemoveDuplicates:

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K4:K" & Lastrow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BL3")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4:C" & Lastrow).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BM3")
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("BL4:BM" & Lastrow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: this would still take the range between C and K. Instead of C or K.

Comment: Thank you for fixing your typo! Also thank you on the tip regarding breaking up the the copy and pastes, I didn't exactly see that is where I went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I got around to testing this, and it seems I only get the very first result. Do you have any tips?

Comment: Step through the code and see what the values of lastrow equals what you expect.  Make sure the paste looks like it should before the removeduplicates.

Comment: I am trying to do the whole column instead of one cell in a particular column/row(just cant include rows 1,2,3). Distinguishing k:k will give me the full row while k4:k will give me a cell. I'm a bit confused how to go about this. thanks!

Comment: What does `Lastrow` equal?

Comment: you can disregard that. Since I'm not familiar with the syntax It took me a while to figure it out. You were correct regarding a Lastrow issue. Thank you again! You are a life saver!

Comment: I have not. I marked your answer as helpful/correct a while back however.

Comment: @Josh I hate it when someone will down vote with out the courtesy of explaining why.  Seems a little cowardly myself.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Are you calling me a liar and a coward?

Comment: @Josh neither, I was making a general complaint about people that down vote answers without the courtesy of an explanation.  Sorry about the confusion.  It was not directed at you.  I very rarely attack, I am more of a walk away when my ire is up.  Life is too short to argue. I like a good debate but if it gets heated I tend to stop.

Comment: My account sadly doesn't have 125 rep to down-vote you. However, I agree. It would be best if one could complement regarding what they seen to be not helpful. However, I marked your answer as correct, and don't have any need to down vote you as you helped me solve my issue.